# About derivation of Navier Stokes Equation

Tags: mathematics, navier-stokes

[image]

Following the steps of derivation, everything is clear just for one small argument which is:

[image]

Why is the divergence of the transpose of gradient equal to gradient of the divergence, and why does it vanish? By the way, **$u$** is the velocity vector field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using index notation ([Einstein convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is used)

$$
div(u) = \partial_k u^k
$$

$$
grad(u) = \partial_a u^b
$$

Therefore, the statement in the question is just the fact that partial derivatives commute:

$$
\partial_j \partial_i  u^j = \partial_i \partial_j u^j 
$$

Comment: Thanks, but what about the transpose and vanishing of the divergence of $u$ ?

Comment: the transpose is just a "useless" symbol used to recreate the "row-column" product. Once you go to index notation there is no need for it. In your case, the result is zero because your are considering an incompressible fluid (it is written in the first line of the picture you posted) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow

Comment: Thanks! I understand now

Comment: see also this question, it may help you to understand the formal aspects of Navier Stokes and index notation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142588/226902