Component notation and matrix notation for gradient of vector
I'm trying to understand vector and tensor notation, but I'm coming across some difficulties. Say I have vector $\vec{u}$ and I compute its gradient $\nabla \vec{u}$. Then I get a tensor $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$. If I write explicitly all its components, I get
$$\nabla {\bf u} = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\\
\end{Bmatrix}.$$ I'm aware that generally tensors are not the same thing as a matrix. How shall I deal with this quantity though: is it a matrix?
If I compute $\vec{u} \cdot \nabla \vec{u} = u_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}=s_i$, where $s_i$ the different component of a vector ($s_1$, $s_2$, $s_3$)? However, if I were to do this as matrix manipulation (row by columns) $$(u_1,u_2, u_3) \cdot \begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\\
\end{Bmatrix},$$ I would get $s_i= u_i \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}.$ Could someone help me to understand to write component and matrix forms in consistent and correct form?

You created that matrix by explicitly writing all its components $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$ in it. But you could also do this in another way, creating the transpose of that matrix.

The best thing in physics is to use index notation and summation convention.
This makes absolutely clear what $s_i=u_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$ is.

Writing this in matrix vector notation (if you insist) do the obvious
$$ \begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\
\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\
\end{Bmatrix}\pmatrix{u_1\u_2\ u_3},.
$$ More important than that is to know what $(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ represents: the directional derivative of $u$ w.r.t. itself.

this is what gets me confused though. I would say the matrix vector notation you wrote is $\nabla \vec{u} \cdot \vec{u}$ instead of $\vec{u} \cdot \nabla \vec{u}$

This has been discussed a million times: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160229/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375826/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142588/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741360/25301 and so on

The skinny is that it is better to view $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla$ as an operator, $u_i\partial_i$ that operates on a vector: $u_i\partial_iu_j$.

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear and well focussed question.

It is clear, but it is not focused at all as it basically is asking for a textbook chapter explanation on how to write vectors/tenors using index notation (or, worse, asking for users opinions on the matter). IMO, this should not have been re-opened until OP narrowed this down from requiring such a textbook for an answer.

yes indeed, looking at $\vec{u} \cdot \nabla$ as an operator on a vector makes it much easier to understand if. That said, if I want to use matrix manipulation I'm still unable to understand it, unless coming to terms that matrix manipulation cannot be used (I have the same issue if trying to write in matrix form the divergence of a tensor. Unless I were to use the transpose as said by Jos)? If there's a textbook chapter explanation which helps me to understand the issue I'm happy to have a read, but I couldn't find any satisfactory explanation hence the post.
